# django safe filter not working as expected

Tags: python, html, django

I have the text: input=`"some<br/>text"`

```
<div>{{input|safe}}</div>
```

is showing up as I want

```
some
text
```

but

```
<textarea>{{input|safe}}</textarea>
```

is showing up

```
some<br/>text
```

I tried `|linebreaks`, which made the text appear like:

```
<p>some<br/>text</p>
```

How can I make the text show up inside textarea escaped like one in div above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything involved is working as expected. `safe` tells the template engine not to escape HTML tags, but you're trying to replace `<br/>` with a newline character - textareas don't interpret HTML, they show exactly what they contain. `linebreaks` is for going in the other direction, turning newlines into something that will break a line in HTML.

I don't see a way to do this with the the built in tags and filters - you'll probably have to either edit the text in your view or write your own filter.